# firebase read and write - in one event

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i have a real time firebase database  ...

1 - i need to create a child when there is no child exist in database in the name "book"
book structure:

```
"book":[{slno:1,
"name":"harry potter",
"author":"J. K. Rowling"
}]
```

2-  if database have the child named "book" then i need to create new child for "book"
but this time i want the "slno" , last added child's "slno + 1"

```
{ slno:"//last added child's slno + 1",
"name":"new book",
"author":"sample author"
}
```

tell me a best way to write a code on above situation ...
i am new to firebase...

[platform : Android]

i already tried this[and it's working]
but i don't know its good solution when happen database write operation
from multiple divices at same time [i want , never repeat slno]
... any one have better solution

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        rootRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasChild("book")) {
                    // run some code
                    secondtime();


                }else {


                    final DatabaseReference databaseP2 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

        BookModelClass bookModel = new BookModelClass(1,"harry potter","J. K. Rowling");
            databaseP2.child("book").push().setValue(bookModel);
                }


            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });






 private void secondtime(){
    final DatabaseReference databaseP2 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    Query lastQuery = databaseP2.child("book").orderByKey().limitToLast(1);
    lastQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            int slno = 0 ;
            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                 slno =postSnapshot.child("slno").getValue(Integer.class);

            }

            final DatabaseReference databaseP2 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("book");

           BookModelClass bookModel = new BookModelClass(slno+1,"new book","sample author");
            databaseP2.push().setValue(bookModel);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            //Handle possible errors.
        }
    });


}
```

Comment: You getting dynamic response from firebase ?

Comment: if there any possiblity for repeat slno ? [in my last code section on question(when a same time event from multiple divices)]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the new value of the node depends on the existing value (or its existence at all), you'll want to [use a Firebase Database transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions) for this operation.

This means you'll need to read the entire `book` node, but your current solution also does that, so it's the same in read performance. It'll be something along these lines:

```
rootRef.runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {
    @Override
    public Transaction.Result doTransaction(MutableData mutableData) {
      if (mutableData.hasChildren()) {
        int slno = 0 ;
        for (MutableData postData: mutableData.getChildren()) {
             slno = postData.child("slno").getValue(Integer.class);
        }

       BookModelClass bookModel = new BookModelClass(slno+1,"new book","sample author");
       String newKey = rootRef.push().getKey();

        // Set value and report transaction success
        mutableData.child(newKey).setValue(bookModel);
      }
      return Transaction.success(mutableData);
    }

    @Override
    public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, boolean b,
                           DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        // Transaction completed
        Log.d(TAG, "bookTransaction:onComplete:" + databaseError);
    }
});
```